# Why can't I see keyframes in the timeline?

Tags: animation, modifiers, keyframes, graph-editor, timeline

I was doing some animation, when I didn't know how to animate using edit mode. Someone showed me a tutorial on YouTube by using hooks. It managed to work, but then I began to realise that the keyframes were not showing AT ALL in the timeline , despite clicking on the selected object with the auto-keying. Have I done something wrong?

[image]

Comment: maybe you've pushed the action in the NLA, and what's playing is the NLA action, there's no action in the Dopesheet anymore?

Comment: Hook keyframes belong to the hook object, not the deformed object.

Comment: I already deleted the hook, but the keyframe won't show. Should I try to wait for a couple of months?

Comment: Why wait? add more information to your question and consider sharing your file. The image you  posted does not give any information for other users to help you.  If you are setting keyframes those will show on the NLA or the Curve editor.

Comment: Did you accidentally drag the timeline up? It sometimes hides the keyframes if you did, and you will have to drag it back down.

Comment: I can't video it, so I had to take a screenshot only. The keyframes did not show anywhere including the graph editor and dope sheet, only in my location settings.

Answer (score 11):

I just realized that I scrolled my timeline down.

Using <kbd>Shift</kbd> while using the <kbd>MMW</kbd> (Middle mouse wheel) the contents of the Timeline can be scrolled up (out of the visual area), and thus keys become hidden.